# In Azure Devops, how can I deploy an exe file to as server as part of release (or something similar)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops

A solution consists of...:

- Web app
- Console app ("jobserver", which pulls jobs and processes them)

All is C#, .Net Core 5.

I have continuous deployment set up, so new versions of the web app are deployed to Azure Web App automatically.

However, the console app, I cannot figure out a good way to deploy to a Windows server (or pull). Right now, I go to the server, stop the app if it is not doing anything (otherwise I wait a bit). Then I copy the files over and start it up again. All manually.

I can think of several complicated workarounds, but I am thinking there must be easier way.

What are some ways the deployment of exe file could be handled? How are others handling this?

Ps. The console app cannot run on Azure Web App or as WebJob or similar, because it has requirements that means it has to run on a "real" windows server.

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways but what we did was install an azure agent on the server. Then on a special pipeline we ran manually it would download the latest CI artifact and then run some powershell scripts to put the files in the right place, make a backup and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [PowerShell on Target machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops) or [SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops) tasks to run commands on a remote machine. Similarly, to copy files, you can use [Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) or [Copy Files Over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops) to copy your `.exe` to the server.